# Finite Limits, Exponentiation and Sub-Object Classifiers imply Finite Co-Limits

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, topos-theory

I recently started studying topoi and the book I am using defines them as categories that have all finite limits and co-limits, exponentiation and sub-object classifiers. The book briefly remarks that finite co-completeness is actually unnecessary as the other three conditions imply it. However, the book itself does not prove this fact. As such, could anyone suggest an easily accessible proof of this result? I am specifically looking for an **online-accessible** paper/book on the proof.

Comment: This is a non-trivial theorem of Paré. You can find it in some textbooks – e.g. _Sheaves in geometry and logic_.

Comment: @ZhenLin Would you happen to know the full name of the author? Even better, do you know the paper he published the theorem in? Thanks.

Comment: Robert Paré (1974) - _Colimits in topoi_.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes. It seems that paper is available online. Thank you. You can post the comment as an answer and I can accept that if you wish.

Comment: The idea of Paré's proof, specialized to the case of the topos $\mathrm{Set}$, is the following. First, show that $\mathrm{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is equivalent to the category of complete atomic Heyting algebras (using the contravariant power set functor). (In classical logic, you can also say "complete atomic Boolean algebras".) Then observe that for any index category $\mathcal{I}$, if $\mathrm{Set}$ possesses all $\mathcal{I}$-shaped limits, then so does the category of complete atomic Heyting algebras. Transporting this observation along the equivalence of categories, ...

Comment: ... we see that $\mathrm{Set}$ possesses all $\mathcal{I}^{\mathrm{op}}$-shaped colimits. For the general case of an arbitrary topos $\mathcal{E}$, one can mimic these arguments using diagrammatic instead of element-based notation. One could also employ the internal language (if one makes sure that the reasoning in justifying its use is not circular).

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt These are helpful comments for reading this technical paper. Appreciations.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt I would say that the idea of Paré's proof, for any topos $C$, is that the power object functor from $C^{op}$ to $C$ is monadic, and hence $C^{op}$ inherits limits from $C$ (as does any category of algebras over a monad)

Comment: @Nex We are in complete agreement. :-) I gave an explicit description of the category of algebras of the induced monad: it is the category of internal complete atomic Boolean algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-trivial theorem of Paré [1974, *[Colimits in topoi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1974-13497-X)*]. You can also find a proof in some textbooks, e.g. *Sheaves in geometry and logic*.